# Раскодировать набор символов

Tags: unicode

Подскажите как можно раскодировать в тестовую строку кодированный набор символов.

```
\u6211\u6765\u81EA\u4E8E\u817E\u8BAF\u5FAE\u535A\u5F00\u653E\u5E73\u53F0
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, для php могу предложить такое решение:

```
echo utfdec('\u6211\u6765\u81EA\u4E8E\u817E\u8BAF\u5FAE\u535A\u5F00\u653E\u5E73\u53F0');

function utfdec($str) {
    return json_decode(sprintf('"%s"', $str));
}
```

В результате получим строку:

```
我来自于腾讯微博开放平台
```

Answer (score 2):

В Python 3:

```
print("\u6211\u6765\u81EA\u4E8E\u817E\u8BAF\u5FAE\u535A\u5F00\u653E\u5E73\u53F0")
```

Вывод:

> ```
> '我来自于腾讯微博开放平台'
> ```